# LARAVEL - How to change Auth::route() paths to custom address

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on **laravel7** Project, I want to change **default Auth::route() route paths**

I have login page and I want to change it to something like: **/random/random2/random3/login**

but laravel auth comes with "/login". how can I edit it?

Comment: You could just define them yourself instead of using `Auth::route()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to prefix them, you can wrap it in a route group:

```
Route::prefix('random/random2/random3/')->group(function(){
    Auth::routes();
}).
```

I haven't tested this but it should work because Laravel references the routes by their name (e.g. `route('login')`) which would stay the same.

Alternatively you could just define your own routes instead of using `Auth::routes()` at all. You can copy [the routes from the `laravel/ui`](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php) package and adjust them as needed.